# java8 stream to create multiple objects based on the list along with the existing properties

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a object which i want to create multiple object's based on the list.

Account.java

```
    class Account{
    @JsonProperty("accountId")
    private Long accountId;
    @JsonProperty("custId")
    private String custId;
    //custName, comments, status
    private String custCode;
    private LocalDate startOn;
    private String loanType;
}
```

Sample input request json:

```
"accountRequest": [
    {
        "accountId": "10EIIP",
        "custId": "11EE",
        "custName": "XYZ",
        "comments": null,
        "status": "active",
        "linkedDetails": [
            {
                "custCode": "001",
                "startOn": "2023-01-01",
                "loanType": "auto"
            },
            {
                "custCode": "002",
                "startOn": "2023-01-15",
                "loanType": "home"
            },
            {
                "custCode": "003",
                "startOn": "2023-02-10",
                "loanType": "home"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Sample java code:

```
List<Account> accountList = new ArrayList<>();
List<AccountRequest> accountRequestList = request.getAccountRequest();
accountRequestList.get(0).getLinkedDetails().forEach(linkedDetails -> {
    Account account = new Account();
    //need to set accountId, custId, custName, comments, status in each account object along with below set values..
    account.setCustCode(linkedDetails.getCustCode());
    account.setStartOn(linkedDetails.getStartOn());
    account.setLoanType(linkedDetails.getLoanType());
    accountList.add(account);
});
```

From "accountRequest" object, i want to iterate "linkedDetails" and based on linkedDetails size i have to create the objects.

**Expected output json:**

```
"accountList": [
    {
        "accountId": "10EIIP",
        "custId": "11EE",
        "custName": "XYZ",
        "comments": null,
        "status": "active",
        "custCode": "001",
        "startOn": "2023-01-01",
        "loanType": "auto"
    },
    {
        "accountId": "10EIIP",
        "custId": "11EE",
        "custName": "XYZ",
        "comments": null,
        "status": "active",
        "custCode": "002",
        "startOn": "2023-01-15",
        "loanType": "home"
    },
    {
        "accountId": "10EIIP",
        "custId": "11EE",
        "custName": "XYZ",
        "comments": null,
        "status": "active",
        "custCode": "003",
        "startOn": "2023-02-10",
        "loanType": "home"
    }
]
```

With the sample java code shown above, the properties accountId, custId, custName, comments, status are null and not copied. Looking for the output json as shown in expected output.

Comment: Well, you never set the comments field.

Comment: @Unmitigated
 How to set to set accountId, custId, custName, comments, status while iterating the linkedDetails ?

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is this.

```
        List<Account> accounts = request.getAccountRequest().stream().flatMap(ac -> ac.getLinkedDetails().stream().map(ld -> {
            Account account = new Account();
            account.setAccountId(ac.getAccountId());
            account.setCustId(ac.getCustId());
            account.setCustCode(ld.getCustCode());
            account.setStartOn(ld.getStartOn());
            account.setLoanType(ld.getLoanType());

            return account;
        })).collect(Collectors.toList());
```